# Aborted connections (Erros reading communication packets)

Tags: mysql, php, connectivity, connections

I set up a new Database Server over a SQL Dump with innoDB MYSQL 5.7 from MYSQL 5.6. The Server running external with many sleeping SMTP connections over 1 Mio a day. I made the server open for connections, start a PHP script, it was running well but my Mailserver have problems with the new Database Server, got many erros and NO connection. I dont know why, ask in lot of boards, nothing helped. Use a Server at the same hosting company low latency, 1 Gbit

```
    2019-09-07T22:52:33.072119Z 25557 [Note] Aborted connection 25557 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.173203Z 25558 [Note] Aborted connection 25558 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.270923Z 25559 [Note] Aborted connection 25559 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.290096Z 25560 [Note] Aborted connection 25560 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.364205Z 25561 [Note] Aborted connection 25561 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.435427Z 25562 [Note] Aborted connection 25562 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.440042Z 25563 [Note] Aborted connection 25563 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.445836Z 25564 [Note] Aborted connection 25564 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.451517Z 25565 [Note] Aborted connection 25565 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.541272Z 25566 [Note] Aborted connection 25566 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.559697Z 25567 [Note] Aborted connection 25567 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.614238Z 25568 [Note] Aborted connection 25568 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.617641Z 25569 [Note] Aborted connection 25569 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.630602Z 25570 [Note] Aborted connection 25570 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.706085Z 25571 [Note] Aborted connection 25571 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.713303Z 25572 [Note] Aborted connection 25572 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.809893Z 25573 [Note] Aborted connection 25573 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-09-07T22:52:33.854610Z 25574 [Note] Aborted connection 25574 to db: 'usr_web0_1' user: 'web0' host: '144.0.22.123' (Got an error reading communication packets)



    # Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients
skip-name-resolve
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-slave-start
innodb_file_per_table=1
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 1G
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 3000
table_open_cache       = 4000
innodb_thread_concurrency     = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 48
innodb_write_io_threads = 48
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 40
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 3G
max_heap_table_size = 3G
innodb_log_file_size = 4G
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
wait_timeout = 31536000
interactive_timeout = 25000
max_connect_errors = 500

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 0
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type    = 0
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME - if possible
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.


Make thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 to reduce threads_created.

Comment: Have you accomplished the 'update' referred to in this url?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html